# Extended WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I needed the ability to do a few extra things with a `WebBrowser` control on a .NET Windows Forms Form, and I found it needed some updates.

So, I made a few. I added some JavaScript manipulation, and a configuration class so that it can be tweaked a lot. I wanted to be able to add and execute arbitrary JavaScript, as well as change how it acts. (By default, it works in Internet Explorer 7 mode, which is dumb. So I figured I would implement all the Feature Control items as well as this change.)

```
/// <summary>
/// Extends the <code>System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser</code> and adds the IsClosing event, as well as some JavaScript manipulation. It also adds some configuration that can be used to customize the operation of the control.
/// </summary>
public class ExtendedWebBrowser : WebBrowser
{
    private const int WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 528;
    private const int WM_DESTROY = 2;

    /// <summary>
    /// This event is called anytime the WebBrowser is set to destroy itself, including Javascript window.close() calls.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> IsClosing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Overrides the default <see cref="WebBrowser.WndProc(ref Message)"/> method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m">The <code>System.Windows.Forms.Message</code> being sent to the control.</param>
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_PARENTNOTIFY)
        {
            if (!DesignMode && m.WParam.ToInt32() == WM_DESTROY)
            {
                IsClosing(this, new EventArgs());
            }

            DefWndProc(ref m);
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Injects some JavaScript to the <see cref="ExtendedWebBrowser"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="javaScript">The code to inject.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the script.</param>
    public HtmlElement InjectScript(string javaScript, string name)
    {
        var head = Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var scriptElement = Document.CreateElement("script");

        scriptElement.Name = name;
        scriptElement.SetAttribute("text", javaScript);

        head.AppendChild(scriptElement);

        return scriptElement;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a JavaScript method in the <see cref="ExtendedWebBrowser"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scriptName">The name of the method to invoke.</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments to pass to the method.</param>
    public void ExecuteScript(string scriptName, params object[] args)
    {
        Document.InvokeScript(scriptName, args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes arbitrary JavaScript code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="script">The code to invoke.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This creates an element with the name <code>arbitrary-script</code> with a javascript method called <code>arbitraryScript</code>. If a method with this name is present in the document, this method may not have the desired effect. If an element with the aforementioned name is present, it will be altered.
    /// </remarks>
    public void ExecuteArbitraryJavaScript(string script)
    {
        var arbitraryScript = Document.GetElementById("arbitrary-script");

        if (arbitraryScript == null)
        {
            arbitraryScript = InjectScript("function arbitraryScript() { " + script + " }", "arbitrary-script");
        }
        else
        {
            arbitraryScript.SetAttribute("text", "function arbitraryScript() { " + script + " }");
        }

        ExecuteScript("arbitraryScript");

        arbitraryScript.SetAttribute("text", "");
    }

    private void SetDWordKey(string baseKey, string name, uint value)
    {
        using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(baseKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
        {
            key.SetValue(name, value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the <see cref="ExtendedWebBrowser"/> with the provided configuration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config">The <see cref="ExtendedWebBrowserConfiguration"/> to update the registry with.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method will update the registry values of all properties with the <see cref="FeatureControlAttribute"/> on them, of the specified key to the provided value in the configuration object.
    /// 
    /// See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx for more information on Feature Controls.
    /// </remarks>
    public void Initialize(ExtendedWebBrowserConfiguration config)
    {
        var name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

        if (name.ToLower() == "devenv.exe" || name.ToLower() == "xdesproc.exe")
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var property in config.GetType().GetProperties().Where(property => Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(FeatureControlAttribute))))
        {
            var attribute = (FeatureControlAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FeatureControlAttribute), true)[0];
            var rawValue = property.GetValue(config);
            var cleanValue = 0u;

            if (rawValue is bool)
            {
                cleanValue = (bool)rawValue ? 1u : 0u;
            }
            else
            {
                cleanValue = (uint)rawValue;
            }

            SetDWordKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\" + attribute.Key, name, cleanValue);
        }
    }
}
```

The configuration class:

```
public class ExtendedWebBrowserConfiguration
{
    private int _emulationVersion;

    public int EmulationVersion
    {
        get { return _emulationVersion; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 7 && value <= 11)
            {
                _emulationVersion = value;
                return;
            }

            throw new ArgumentException("The provided value is invalid. Valid versions are values from 7 through 11.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_RESTRICT_ABOUT_PROTOCOL_IE7
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_RESTRICT_ABOUT_PROTOCOL_IE7")]
    public bool AboutProtocolRestriction { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_SAFE_BINDTOOBJECT
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_SAFE_BINDTOOBJECT")]
    public bool ActiveXBindingSafetyChecks { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_OBJECT_CACHING
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_OBJECT_CACHING")]
    public bool ActiveXObjectCaching { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_RESTRICT_ACTIVEXINSTALL
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_RESTRICT_ACTIVEXINSTALL")]
    public bool ActiveXUpdateRestriction { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_FORCE_ADDR_AND_STATUS
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_FORCE_ADDR_AND_STATUS")]
    public bool AddressAndStatusBarDisplay { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS")]
    public bool AjaxConnectionEvents { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_SHOW_APP_PROTOCOL_WARN_DIALOG
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_SHOW_APP_PROTOCOL_WARN_DIALOG")]
    public bool ApplicationProtocolConfirmation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_BEHAVIORS
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_BEHAVIORS")]
    public bool BinaryBehaviorSecurity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION")]
    public uint BrowserEmulation
    {
        get { return (uint)EmulationVersion * 1000; }
        set { EmulationVersion = (int)value / 1000; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION")]
    public bool ChildWindowClipping { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_MANAGE_SCRIPT_CIRCULAR_REFS
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_MANAGE_SCRIPT_CIRCULAR_REFS")]
    public bool CircularReferencesInScriptManagement { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_ENABLE_SCRIPT_PASTE_URLACTION_IF_PROMPT
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_ENABLE_SCRIPT_PASTE_URLACTION_IF_PROMPT")]
    public bool ClipboardScriptControl { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_BLOCK_SETCAPTURE_XDOMAIN
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_BLOCK_SETCAPTURE_XDOMAIN")]
    public bool CrossDomainCaptureEvent { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_CROSS_DOMAIN_REDIRECT_MITIGATION
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_CROSS_DOMAIN_REDIRECT_MITIGATION")]
    public bool CrossDomainRedirection { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_DOWNLOAD_INITIATOR_HTTP_HEADER
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_DOWNLOAD_INITIATOR_HTTP_HEADER")]
    public bool DebuggingNetworkTrafficRequests { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_DOMSTORAGE
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_DOMSTORAGE")]
    public bool DomWebStorageApiSupport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_CFSTR_INETURLW_DRAGDROP_FORMAT
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_CFSTR_INETURLW_DRAGDROP_FORMAT")]
    public bool DragAndDropUrlFormat { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_FEEDS
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_FEEDS")]
    public bool Feeds { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_RESTRICT_FILEDOWNLOAD
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_RESTRICT_FILEDOWNLOAD")]
    public bool FileDownloadRestrictions { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_BLOCK_CROSS_PROTOCOL_FILE_NAVIGATION
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_BLOCK_CROSS_PROTOCOL_FILE_NAVIGATION")]
    public bool FileProtocolNavigation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_IE6_DEFAULT_FRAME_NAVIGATION_BEHAVIOR
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_IE6_DEFAULT_FRAME_NAVIGATION_BEHAVIOR")]
    public bool FrameContentModification { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_VIEWLINKEDWEBOC_IS_UNSAFE
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_VIEWLINKEDWEBOC_IS_UNSAFE")]
    public bool FrameContentSecurity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING")]
    public bool GpuRendering { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_MAXCONNECTIONSPER1_0SERVER
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_MAXCONNECTIONSPER1_0SERVER")]
    public uint Http10ConnectionMaximum { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// MAXCONNECTIONSPERSERVER
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("MAXCONNECTIONSPERSERVER")]
    public uint Http11ConnectionMaximum { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_IFRAME_MAILTO_THRESHOLD
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_IFRAME_MAILTO_THRESHOLD")]
    public bool IFrameMailToThreshold { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_MIME_TREAT_IMAGE_AS_AUTHORITATIVE
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_MIME_TREAT_IMAGE_AS_AUTHORITATIVE")]
    public bool ImageMimeTypeDetermination { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_SECURITYBAND
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_SECURITYBAND")]
    public bool InformationBarHandling { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_BLOCK_INPUT_PROMPTS
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_BLOCK_INPUT_PROMPTS")]
    public bool InputPromptBlocking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI")]
    public bool IViewObjectLegacyDrawing { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE")]
    public bool LegacyInputModel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_DISABLE_LEGACY_COMPRESSION
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_DISABLE_LEGACY_COMPRESSION")]
    public bool LegacyCompressionSupport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN")]
    public bool LocalMachineLockdown { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_IMG
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_IMG")]
    public bool LocalImageBlocking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT")]
    public bool LocalObjectBlocking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT")]
    public bool LocalScriptBlocking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_MIME_SNIFFING
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_MIME_SNIFFING")]
    public bool MimeTypeDetermination { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_MIME_HANDLING
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_MIME_HANDLING")]
    public bool MimeTypeHandling { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_DISABLE_MK_PROTOCOL
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_DISABLE_MK_PROTOCOL")]
    public bool MKProtocolSupport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_ISOLATE_NAMED_WINDOWS
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_ISOLATE_NAMED_WINDOWS")]
    public bool NamedWindowIsolation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS")]
    public bool NavigationSoundSupport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_PROTOCOL_LOCKDOWN
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_PROTOCOL_LOCKDOWN")]
    public bool ProtocolLockdown { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_RESTRICT_ACTIVEXINSTALL
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_RESTRICT_ACTIVEXINSTALL")]
    public bool ResourceProtocolRestriction { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_DOWNLOAD_PROMPT_META_CONTROL
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_DOWNLOAD_PROMPT_META_CONTROL")]
    public bool SaveDialogButtonHiding { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION")]
    public bool ScriptUrlMitigation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_WARN_ON_SEC_CERT_REV_FAILED
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_WARN_ON_SEC_CERT_REV_FAILED")]
    public bool SecurityCertificateRevocationFailure { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_LOAD_SHDOCLC_RESOURCES
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_LOAD_SHDOCLC_RESOURCES")]
    public bool ShdoclcDllResourceLoading { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING")]
    public bool SpellcheckAndAutoCorrectSupport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_SSLUX
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_SSLUX")]
    public bool SslSecurityAlertDisplay { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_STATUS_BAR_THROTTLING
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_STATUS_BAR_THROTTLING")]
    public bool StatusBarUpdateFrequency { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_RESTRICT_CDL_CLSIDSNIFF
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_RESTRICT_CDL_CLSIDSNIFF")]
    public bool StructuredStorageDetection { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING")]
    public bool TabbedBrowsingShortcutsAndNotifications { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_DISABLE_TELNET_PROTOCOL
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_DISABLE_TELNET_PROTOCOL")]
    public bool TelnetProtocolSupport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_UNC_SAVEDFILECHECK
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_UNC_SAVEDFILECHECK")]
    public bool UncFileSupportForMotW { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE")]
    public bool UsernamesAndPasswordsInUrls { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL")]
    public bool ValidateUrlNavigation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_SHIM_MSHELP_COMBINE
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_SHIM_MSHELP_COMBINE")]
    public bool VisualStudioLegacyHelpSupport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM")]
    public bool WebBrowserControlDocumentZoom { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT")]
    public bool WebBrowserControlPopupManagement { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_WEBOC_MOVESIZECHILD
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_WEBOC_MOVESIZECHILD")]
    public bool WebBrowserControlWindowControl { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_ENABLE_WEB_CONTROL_VISUALS
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_ENABLE_WEB_CONTROL_VISUALS")]
    public bool WebControlVisuals { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_ADDON_MANAGEMENT
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_ADDON_MANAGEMENT")]
    public bool WebOcAddonManagement { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_WEBSOCKET
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_WEBSOCKET")]
    public bool WebSocket { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_AUTHPROMPT
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_AUTHPROMPT")]
    public bool WebSocketAuthenticationPrompt { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_CLOSETIMEOUT
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_CLOSETIMEOUT")]
    public uint WebSocketCloseTimeout { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_MAXCONNECTIONSPERSERVER
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_MAXCONNECTIONSPERSERVER")]
    public uint WebSocketMaximumServerConnections { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_FOLLOWHTTPREDIRECT
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_FOLLOWHTTPREDIRECT")]
    public bool WebSocketFollowRedirects { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS")]
    public bool WindowRestrictions { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_XDOMAINREQUEST
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_XDOMAINREQUEST")]
    public bool XDomainRequestObjectSupport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_XMLHTTP
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_XMLHTTP")]
    public bool XmlHttpRequestObjectSupport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_ZONE_ELEVATION
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_ZONE_ELEVATION")]
    public bool ZoneElevation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_RESTRICTED_ZONE_WHEN_FILE_NOT_FOUND
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_RESTRICTED_ZONE_WHEN_FILE_NOT_FOUND")]
    public bool ZoneHandlingForMissingFiles { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FEATURE_READ_ZONE_STRINGS_FROM_REGISTRY
    /// </summary>
    [FeatureControl("FEATURE_READ_ZONE_STRINGS_FROM_REGISTRY")]
    public bool ZoneStringLoading { get; set; }

    public static readonly ExtendedWebBrowserConfiguration WebBrowserControlDefault = new ExtendedWebBrowserConfiguration
    {
        AboutProtocolRestriction = false,
        ActiveXBindingSafetyChecks = true,
        ActiveXObjectCaching = true,
        ActiveXUpdateRestriction = false,
        AddressAndStatusBarDisplay = false,
        AjaxConnectionEvents = false,
        ApplicationProtocolConfirmation = false,
        BinaryBehaviorSecurity = true,
        BrowserEmulation = 7000u,
        ChildWindowClipping = true,
        CircularReferencesInScriptManagement = true,
        ClipboardScriptControl = true,
        CrossDomainCaptureEvent = true,
        CrossDomainRedirection = true,
        DebuggingNetworkTrafficRequests = false,
        DomWebStorageApiSupport = true,
        DragAndDropUrlFormat = true,
        Feeds = false,
        FileDownloadRestrictions = false,
        FileProtocolNavigation = false,
        FrameContentModification = false,
        FrameContentSecurity = false,
        GpuRendering = false,
        Http10ConnectionMaximum = 6,
        Http11ConnectionMaximum = 6,
        IFrameMailToThreshold = false,
        ImageMimeTypeDetermination = true,
        InformationBarHandling = false,
        InputPromptBlocking = false,
        IViewObjectLegacyDrawing = true,
        LegacyInputModel = true,
        LegacyCompressionSupport = true,
        LocalMachineLockdown = false,
        LocalImageBlocking = false,
        LocalObjectBlocking = false,
        LocalScriptBlocking = false,
        MimeTypeDetermination = true,
        MimeTypeHandling = false,
        MKProtocolSupport = true,
        NamedWindowIsolation = true,
        NavigationSoundSupport = false,
        ProtocolLockdown = false,
        ResourceProtocolRestriction = false,
        SaveDialogButtonHiding = true,
        ScriptUrlMitigation = false,
        SecurityCertificateRevocationFailure = false,
        ShdoclcDllResourceLoading = false,
        SpellcheckAndAutoCorrectSupport = false,
        SslSecurityAlertDisplay = false,
        StatusBarUpdateFrequency = false,
        StructuredStorageDetection = false,
        TabbedBrowsingShortcutsAndNotifications = false,
        TelnetProtocolSupport = false,
        UncFileSupportForMotW = false,
        UsernamesAndPasswordsInUrls = false,
        ValidateUrlNavigation = false,
        VisualStudioLegacyHelpSupport = true,
        WebBrowserControlDocumentZoom = false,
        WebBrowserControlPopupManagement = true,
        WebBrowserControlWindowControl = false,
        WebControlVisuals = false,
        WebOcAddonManagement = false,
        WebSocket = true,
        WebSocketAuthenticationPrompt = false,
        WebSocketCloseTimeout = 15000,
        WebSocketMaximumServerConnections = 6,
        WebSocketFollowRedirects = false,
        WindowRestrictions = true,
        XDomainRequestObjectSupport = true,
        XmlHttpRequestObjectSupport = true,
        ZoneElevation = true,
        ZoneHandlingForMissingFiles = false,
        ZoneStringLoading = false,
    };

    public static readonly ExtendedWebBrowserConfiguration InternetExplorerDefault = new ExtendedWebBrowserConfiguration
    {
        AboutProtocolRestriction = true,
        ActiveXBindingSafetyChecks = true,
        ActiveXObjectCaching = true,
        ActiveXUpdateRestriction = false,
        AddressAndStatusBarDisplay = true,
        AjaxConnectionEvents = true,
        ApplicationProtocolConfirmation = true,
        BinaryBehaviorSecurity = true,
        BrowserEmulation = 11000u,
        ChildWindowClipping = true,
        CircularReferencesInScriptManagement = true,
        ClipboardScriptControl = false,
        CrossDomainCaptureEvent = true,
        CrossDomainRedirection = true,
        DebuggingNetworkTrafficRequests = false,
        DomWebStorageApiSupport = true,
        DragAndDropUrlFormat = true,
        Feeds = true,
        FileDownloadRestrictions = false,
        FileProtocolNavigation = true,
        FrameContentModification = false,
        FrameContentSecurity = true,
        GpuRendering = true,
        Http10ConnectionMaximum = 6,
        Http11ConnectionMaximum = 6,
        IFrameMailToThreshold = true,
        ImageMimeTypeDetermination = true,
        InformationBarHandling = true,
        InputPromptBlocking = true,
        IViewObjectLegacyDrawing = true,
        LegacyInputModel = false,
        LegacyCompressionSupport = true,
        LocalMachineLockdown = true,
        LocalImageBlocking = true,
        LocalObjectBlocking = true,
        LocalScriptBlocking = true,
        MimeTypeDetermination = true,
        MimeTypeHandling = true,
        MKProtocolSupport = true,
        NamedWindowIsolation = true,
        NavigationSoundSupport = false,
        ProtocolLockdown = false,
        ResourceProtocolRestriction = true,
        SaveDialogButtonHiding = true,
        ScriptUrlMitigation = true,
        SecurityCertificateRevocationFailure = false,
        ShdoclcDllResourceLoading = false,
        SpellcheckAndAutoCorrectSupport = false,
        SslSecurityAlertDisplay = false,
        StatusBarUpdateFrequency = true,
        StructuredStorageDetection = false,
        TabbedBrowsingShortcutsAndNotifications = true,
        TelnetProtocolSupport = true,
        UncFileSupportForMotW = true,
        UsernamesAndPasswordsInUrls = true,
        ValidateUrlNavigation = true,
        VisualStudioLegacyHelpSupport = false,
        WebBrowserControlDocumentZoom = true,
        WebBrowserControlPopupManagement = true,
        WebBrowserControlWindowControl = false,
        WebControlVisuals = false,
        WebOcAddonManagement = false,
        WebSocket = true,
        WebSocketAuthenticationPrompt = false,
        WebSocketCloseTimeout = 15000,
        WebSocketMaximumServerConnections = 6,
        WebSocketFollowRedirects = false,
        WindowRestrictions = true,
        XDomainRequestObjectSupport = true,
        XmlHttpRequestObjectSupport = true,
        ZoneElevation = true,
        ZoneHandlingForMissingFiles = false,
        ZoneStringLoading = false,
    };
}
```

And the attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class FeatureControlAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public FeatureControlAttribute(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd argue against having a setter on the `Key` property of the `FeatureControlAttribute` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much to say, your code looks well formatted and you are using good and meaningful names to name your things.

Nevertheless I would likte to say that in the `ExtendedWebBrowser` class the order of the methods could be improved. You are calling `SetDWordKey()` in the `Initialize()` method which involves an upwards scroll to get there. I would expect a method which is only called by one other method to follow the calling method.

---

In the `ExtendedWebBrowserConfiguration` you should extract the magic numbers `7` and `11` to meaningful constants.

Comment: 7 and 11 are [lucky numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps), obviously!